# Can PL/SQL procedures call themselves recursively?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Using PL/SQL, it is possible to call a stored function from within that same function. This can be demonstrated with the following example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factorial(x in number)
RETURN number 
IS
   f number;
BEGIN
   IF x = 0 THEN
      f := 1;
   ELSE
      f := x * factorial(x-1);
   END IF;
RETURN f;
END;
/

DECLARE
   num number;
   factorial number;
BEGIN
   num := &num;
   factorial := factorial(num);
   dbms_output.put_line(' The factorial of '|| num || ' is ' || factorial);
END;
/
```

Can this be done using PL/SQL stored procedures as well?

Comment: Why nor just try it to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a procedure that calls itself recursively in PL/SQL. Here is an example - implementing the factorial.

With that said, don't ever write a procedure (or a function like yours) without error handling. If you don't understand why, change `5` to `5.3` in the anonymous block below, and you'll see why.

CODE window:

```
create or replace procedure fact ( x in number, x_fact out number )
as
begin
  if x = 0 then x_fact := 1;
  else          fact(x-1, x_fact);
                x_fact := x * x_fact;
  end if;
end;
/

set serveroutput on

declare
  z number;
begin
  fact(5, z);
  dbms_output.put_line(z);
end;
/
```

SCRIPT OUTPUT window (matching each "result" to the corresponding part of the code left as an exercise):

```
Procedure FACT compiled

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

120
```

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly call PL/SQL functions recursively (with all the usual warnings about the dangers of doing so in any language!).

You are, however, going to run into trouble if you name a local variable the same as your function. You will, for example, get this error when you try to execute the block:

```
PLS-00222: no function with name 'FACTORIAL' exists in this scope
```

Comment: What you show here is certainly correct; but that wasn't the question.